# What does --record do in Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I've seen:

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record
```

What is `--record` doing here? I've tried a deployment with it and without it + scaling/image replacing (set image) + checking rollout status etc but I dont see any difference.

I'm probably missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll record your changes for a given deployment.

```
kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record=true
```

Later you can rollback using revision number if needed.

> Note: You can specify the --record flag to write the command executed
>   in the resource annotation kubernetes.io/change-cause. The recorded
>   change is useful for future introspection. For example, to see the
>   commands executed in each Deployment revision.

Refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

Comment: I edited the answer to include the best explanation/objective explanation possible taken from the documentation.